# Mix razor @ and @: syntax in same line

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to make a post call to the controller. 
Normally it can be done like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedPermissions", "Mycontroller")'
var postResult = $.post(url, { userId: GetUserId(), selectedRowsIDs: selectedIDs });
```

But I need to set the controller name from javascript.

I have tried this

```
var controller = applicationsPageControl.GetActiveTab().name;
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedPermissions", @:controller)'
var postResult = $.post(url, { userId: GetUserId(), selectedRowsIDs: selectedIDs });
```

and this:

```
var controller = applicationsPageControl.GetActiveTab().name;
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedPermissions", @:controller @)'
var postResult = $.post(url, { userId: GetUserId(), selectedRowsIDs: selectedIDs });
```

But I get syntax error: Razor expect the closing parenthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You kinda beat me to it there!

```
var controller = applicationsPageControl.GetActiveTab().name;
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedPermissions", "PCN")';
url = url.replace("PCN", controller);
var postResult = $.post(url, { userId: GetUserId(), selectedRowsIDs: selectedIDs }
```

Yes, you use a placeholder.
In case it is useful to you going forward, if you have an ActionLink and you want to change a parameter dynamically you can also use a placeholder.

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "action", "controller", routeValues: new { myParam = "__plc__" }, htmlAttributes: new { id="myLink" })
```

and in the javascript... (here, JQuery is used to send the browser's culture as a parameter. This is of course only known at runtime and Razor's outputting of the link won't know what value to put).

```
<script>
$(function () {

    $('#myLink').prop('href', $('#myLink').prop('href').replace('__plc__', navigator.language ? navigator.language : navigator['userLanguage']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best way, but it's works:

```
var controller = applicationsPageControl.GetActiveTab().name;
var url = '@Url.Action("DeleteSelectedPermissions", "PCN")';
url = url.replace("PCN", controller);
var postResult = $.post(url, { userId: GetUserId(), selectedRowsIDs: selectedIDs });
```